# Is there any way to query user info from Keycloak API rest with a set of users Ids in one call?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, keycloak

Let's say I have a set of user Ids in an array or similar structure

```js
['as76asd7fd767', 'fd9dc8zc009cz','scscd09acda8asc8vbd8',...]
```

I want to get the User Representation Info from those Ids, but I don't want to do a user call for each isolated userId. Can it be possible to provide a set of userIds and get the respective users representation?